# Как вернуть в начальный цикл?

Tags: python, циклы, валидация

Не знаю, как кратко описать проблему, попробую

```
while True:
    if not user_input:
        while True:
            user_input = input('Enter your ID: ')
            try:
                int(user_input)
                if len(user_input) !=11:
                    raise UserWarning
            except ValueError:
                print('Code is not numeric')
            except UserWarning:
                if len(user_input) > 11:
                    print('Code is too long')
                else:
                    print('Code is too short')
            else:
                print(user_input)
                break
    user_choice = input('Please choose:\n'
                        '1.Get gender\n'
                        '2.Get date of birth\n'
                        '3.Get region of birth\n'
                        '4. Validate ID\n'
                        '5.Change ID\n'
                        '0.Exit\n'
                        '--->')
    elif user_choice == '5':
    pass
```

так вот, когда я хочу вернуть 5 пункт user_choice (Change ID) в саамый начальный цикл, что бы я смог вставить новый айди - у меня это не получается, как это сделать, как сделать так, что бы я ввел новый айди и проходил дальше проверку?
Объяснил как мог, если не понятно, задавайте еще вопросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как пример

```
user_input =''
while True:
    if not user_input:
        while True:
            user_input = input('Enter your ID: ')
            try:
                 int(user_input)
            except ValueError:
                print('Code is not numeric')
                continue
            if len(user_input) > 11:
                print('Code is too long')
                continue
            elif len(user_input) < 11:
                print('Code is too short')
                continue
            print(user_input)
            break
    user_choice = input('Please choose:\n'
                        '1.Get gender\n'
                        '2.Get date of birth\n'
                        '3.Get region of birth\n'
                        '4. Validate ID\n'
                        '5.Change ID\n'
                        '0.Exit\n'
                        '--->')
    if user_choice == '0':
        break
    elif user_choice == '5':
        user_input = ''
        continue
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь новичку, Сергей, все работает!